# How to use unique function with blank/missing values

Tags: r, unique, na

How is it possible to make the below data frame rows uniquely depend on the second column when there are blank/missing values?

```
> head(interproscan)
                V1        V14
1 sp0000001-mRNA-1           
2 sp0000001-mRNA-1           
3 sp0000001-mRNA-1           
4 sp0000005-mRNA-1 GO:0003723
5 sp0000006-mRNA-1 GO:0016021
6 sp0000006-mRNA-1 GO:0016021


> head(unique(interproscan[ , 1:2] ))
                 V1                              V14
1  sp0000001-mRNA-1                                 
4  sp0000005-mRNA-1                       GO:0003723
5  sp0000006-mRNA-1                       GO:0016021
7  sp0000006-mRNA-2                       GO:0016021
9  sp0000006-mRNA-3                       GO:0016021
```

The aim would be:

```
                 V1                              V14
1  sp0000001-mRNA-1                                 
4  sp0000005-mRNA-1                       GO:0003723
5  sp0000006-mRNA-1                       GO:0016021
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: `library(tidyverse); interproscan %>% distinct(V14, .keep_all = T)` works for you aim.  Is there something else?

Comment: `library(tidyverse); > interproscan %>% distinct(V14, .keep_all = T)
                 V1 V14
1: sp0000001-mRNA-1  NA
> head(interproscan)
                 V1 V14
1: sp0000001-mRNA-1  NA
2: sp0000001-mRNA-1  NA
3: sp0000001-mRNA-1  NA
4: sp0000005-mRNA-1  NA
5: sp0000006-mRNA-1  NA
6: sp0000006-mRNA-1  NA`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with a data frame or data table:

```
interproscan <- data.frame(interproscan)

unique(interproscan)
```

Output:

```
                V1        V14
1 sp0000001-mRNA-1           
4 sp0000005-mRNA-1 GO:0003723
5 sp0000006-mRNA-1 GO:0016021
```

Sample data:

```
require(data.table)
interproscan <- fread("V1,               V14
                       sp0000001-mRNA-1,           
                       sp0000001-mRNA-1,          
                       sp0000001-mRNA-1,            
                       sp0000005-mRNA-1, GO:0003723
                       sp0000006-mRNA-1, GO:0016021
                       sp0000006-mRNA-1, GO:0016021")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify `V1` to group by it the way you're intending. I use `gsub` to discard the last `-number` suffix.

```
library(dplyr)
ans <- df %>%
         group_by(gsub("-\\d","",V1), V14) %>%   # now it groups the way you want
         arrange(V1) %>%   # unnecessary for your toy example but just in case for your full data
         slice(1) %>%     # select top row-entry
         ungroup() %>%
         select(-4)     # discard intermediate grouping variable
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     id               V1        V14
  <int>            <chr>      <chr>
1     1 sp0000001-mRNA-1           
2     4 sp0000005-mRNA-1 GO:0003723
3     5 sp0000006-mRNA-1 GO:0016021
```

Data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L), V1 = c("sp0000001-mRNA-1", 
"sp0000001-mRNA-1", "sp0000001-mRNA-1", "sp0000005-mRNA-1", "sp0000006-mRNA-1", 
"sp0000006-mRNA-1", "sp0000006-mRNA-2", "sp0000006-mRNA-3"), 
    V14 = c("", "", "", "GO:0003723", "GO:0016021", "GO:0016021", 
    "GO:0016021", "GO:0016021")), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("id", 
"V1", "V14"), row.names = c(NA, -8L))


  id               V1        V14
1  1 sp0000001-mRNA-1           
2  2 sp0000001-mRNA-1           
3  3 sp0000001-mRNA-1           
4  4 sp0000005-mRNA-1 GO:0003723
5  5 sp0000006-mRNA-1 GO:0016021
6  6 sp0000006-mRNA-1 GO:0016021
7  7 sp0000006-mRNA-2 GO:0016021
8  9 sp0000006-mRNA-3 GO:0016021
```